# Encrypted pdf files crashes on UIWebView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I am trying to open pdf files in my UIWebView in below steps.

self.docViewer is a strong property.

```
    self.docViewer.delegate = self;
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:docurl]];
    [self.docViewer loadRequest:urlReq];
```

It opens normal pdf files and password protected files with no issues.

When the file is an encrypted one, it crashes after executing delegate methods.

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

with below log

```
    unsupported security handler `Adobe.PubSec'.
    FlateDecode: decoding error: incorrect header check.
    FlateDecode: decoding error: incorrect header check.
    unsupported security handler `Adobe.PubSec'.
```

I checked all possible ways mentioned in suggested treads. I didn't find any solution.
Could anyone please help me out of this crash.Thanks a Lot

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted" file? You mean with a key and specific crypto algorithm? In this case, it's normal that the webView doesn't know how to open the file. You have to decrypt your file and then load the data with the webview

Comment: I am getting the pdf files from web. So, i don't know whether the file is normal/passcode protected/encrypted/corrupted. Any way the app should not crash while loading the file. 
Is there any way to check if the file is encrypted or corrupted ?